# How I can get items of filter? R

Tags: r, rvest

How I can get items of filter?
I need to get two vectors from filter: catalogs and names. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Q4CB.png)

I use [filter left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKXP1.png) but it didn't work

```
library(rvest)
my_url <- "https://intertop.ua/catalog/odezhda/muzhskaya/napapijri/"
my_read_url <- read_html(my_url)
my_nodes <- html_nodes(my_read_url, ".filter-left")
html_text(my_nodes)
my_nodes
```

I read many topics, but it didn't help.

Comment: In your image what is catalogs? Is it the href?

Comment: Any update on this?